# Iterate through a Sorted Mongoose Collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, foreach, mongoose

I'm new to JavaScript, MongoDB, and Mongoose.

I have a collection called "students" from db "demodb".
In my JavaScript file, I've made a Mongoose schema called "student" for collection "students".
A "student" has a "name", "gender", and "major" (all of type String).

I'd like to be able to first sort the students by field (alphabetically by "name") and then for each student perform some operation using *Mongoose within JavaScript*.

I've looked around, but have either found syntax for the Mongo shell (not what I want) or examples that haven't worked for me.

I'm familiar with Java and would like to be to do something that like this ideally (after sorting).

```
for(Object currentStudent: students) {
  // do something
}
```

Something like this would also be nice.

```
while(students.hasNext()) {
  Object currentStudent = students.?; //some command to store the current student
  // do something
}
```

Thank you in advance. I apologize if this question seems trivial.

Comment: yourCollection.forEach - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

Getting your head around async programming in node.js is a bit of a pain if you're new to the concepts. Have a look at the last part of [this link](http://learnmongodbthehardway.com/ex3.html) for some lessons to avoid.

Basically

if you write

```
for(var i = 0; i < objects.length;i++) {
  var object = objects[i]
  db.save(object, function(err, result) {
  }
}
```

All the save operations are executed in parallel, not serially like you would expect in Java. Wrapping your head around this is the first step. You can use some libraries like step or async to help you with the orchestration of calls and iterations.